# Problem with a preloader and google analytics

Tags: actionscript-3, google-analytics, preloader, flash-cs5

I'm using Google analytics in my flash app. It works perfectly, but the time to publich the app came and I'm using an external swf. as preloader, which only consists in an small progress bar and summons my Flash app once it's completely loaded.

Now i'm getting this error:

Error #1009: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object

at com.google.analytics.core::IdleTimer()
 at com.google.analytics::GATracker/_trackerFactory()
 at com.google.analytics::GATracker/_factory()
 at com.google.analytics::GATracker()

If I comment my GATracker object, everything works perfectly. I tried including the google analytic libraries in my preloader, but didn't work. I'm really confused since everything works fine without the preloader.

Any suggestion is apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the libraries is not sufficient, if you have a null object error, it would suggest that you need to create your GATracker object in the preloader.